# Moneybookers integration

Tags: forms, payment, gateway

I am trying to integrate moneybookers gateway from a from.

My code is:

```
<div class="form-row">
 <label for="contactform_name" class="form-label">Votre question</label>
 <div><textarea name="counttextarea" id="counttextarea" cols="45" rows="5" style="width: 400px;padding: 10px;"></textarea></div>
<div><span name="countchars" id="countchars"></span> Lettres restantes
<br><br>
Your price: <span name="percent" id="percent"></span></div>

                            </div>
```

When user fill the form an amount is generated depending on the total characters and appears in "your price" field

My question is what value I have to enter in the moneybookers field: `<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="">`to get the amount generated?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

this is the base form:

```
<form action="{{ moneybookersURL }}" method="post" id="moneybookersForm">
<input type="hidden" name="pay_to_email" value="{{ moneybookersEmail }}"/>
<input type="hidden" name="status_url" value="{{ moneybookersIPN }}"/> 
<input type="hidden" name="language" value="EN"/>
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="{{ amount }}"/>
<input type="hidden" name="currency" value="GBP"/>
<input type="hidden" name="detail1_description" value="{{ title }}"/>
<input type="hidden" name="detail1_text" value="{{ orderId }}"/>
<input type="submit" value="MoneyBookers"/>
</form>
```

if you want to add more than one product, just pass your products to gateway page and in a loop add all inputs